# javascript: document.getElementsByName("sample[]") not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbyname

I have a form where you can append additional input if needed. So I named my form like this.

```
<input type="text" name="sample[]" />
```

I want to access all the value of the inputs with a name "sample[]" and store it in an array using javascript. I used this code below:

```
 var sample = document.getElementsByName(sample[]);
```

How can I get all the values individually? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!!

Comment: putting [] in the input name doesn't look like a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your js function and you will get input values in values array.
Here I am getting a NodeList of all elements with name = "sample[]" and converting to Array for easy processing of data.

```
var sample = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByName('sample[]'));
var values = sample.map((o) => o.value);
```

Tested it and following is the link to fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/mfw4rv9o/13/

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have one question, how can I access each value individually? Sorry I'm a beginner in this.

Comment: @trumanblack1025 what do you mean by individually. All values are in array, you can get individual values by values[0], values[1] etc.

Answer (score 0):

String value 'sample[]' is totally different from eval value of `sample[]`. Hence is the confusion over all.
If you're very sure you want to pass 'sample[]' as a (string) value of `name` prop of , make sure you stringify it and add it.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the input is `name="sample[]"`. The parameter of [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) is the value of the name attribute of the element(s) so that should be `"sample[]"`.

getElementsByName will return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) for which you could use a `foreach` to loop over, use [item](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/item) to return a node from a NodeList by index or use an index `sample[0]`.

To get all the values in an array in es6 you could use the spread operator and map:

`let items = [...document.getElementsByName("sample[]")].map(i => i.value);`

```js
var sample = document.getElementsByName("sample[]");
console.log(sample[0].value);
console.log(sample.item(0).value);
let items = [...document.getElementsByName("sample[]")].map(i => i.value);
console.log(items);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="sample[]" value="value1" />
  <input type="text" name="sample[]" value="value2" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES6:

```
var values = [...document.querySelectorAll("input[name='sample[]']")].map(x => x.value);
```

But I would refrain from using `sample[]` as the input name.

Answer (score -1):

`var sample = document.getElementsByName('sample[]');`
Add quotes between `sample[]`. Try to avoid `[]` in input name.

Comment: "Try to avoid `[]` in input name." why would they? It's the only way to define arrays in FormData understandable by php. (Ok, they should also *Try to avoid php altogether*, but...)

Comment: I was looking for `[]` in input name. I didn't know this technique. Sorry